# Sq-lite database retrieve data to array list

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

I want to get all database value into my arraylist and show in logcat. but i am facing some problem during getting value from arraylist. i put my hole code, i am able to get value but getting last value from model.

my MainActivity

```
package com.example.databasework;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btnInsertCW, btnInsertCD, btnGetAllVAlue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnInsertCW = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInsertCW);
    btnInsertCD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInsertCD);
    btnGetAllVAlue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetAllVAlue);
    btnInsertCW.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Database transactionDb = new Database(getApplicationContext());
            TransactionModel transactionModel = new TransactionModel();
            transactionDb.open();
            transactionModel.setDate("14/2/2015");
            transactionModel.setTime("11:12:15");
            transactionModel.setEnrollment("CW");
            transactionDb.insert(transactionModel);
            transactionDb.close();

        }
    });

    btnInsertCD.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Database transactionDb = new Database(getApplicationContext());
            TransactionModel transactionModel = new TransactionModel();
            transactionDb.open();
            transactionModel.setDate("28/3/2014");
            transactionModel.setTime("09:08:06");
            transactionModel.setEnrollment("CD");
            transactionDb.insert(transactionModel);
            transactionDb.close();

        }
    });

    btnGetAllVAlue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ArrayList<TransactionModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<TransactionModel>();

            Database transactionDb      = new Database(getApplicationContext());
            transactionDb.open();
            arrayList = transactionDb.getReportPrintTrns();
            transactionDb.close();

            System.err.println(arrayList);

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++)
            {
                TransactionModel transactionModel = arrayList.get(i);
                System.err.println(transactionModel.getEnrollment());
            }

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

in arrayList = transactionDb.getReportPrintTrns(); want all database value.

My Database

```
package com.example.databasework;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class Database {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME               = "KisanMitra.db";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE               = "TransactionDb";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION               = 1;

public static final String TrnsNo                       = "TrnsNo";
public static final String Enrollment                   = "Enrollment";
public static final String CardNumber                   = "CardNumber";
public static final String EnrollmentAmount             = "EnrollmentAmount";
public static final String Date                         = "Date";
public static final String Time                         = "Time";
public static final String ReturnStatus                 = "ReturnStatus";
public static final String TotalCashWithdrawalAmount    = "TotalCashWithdrawalAmount";
public static final String TotalCashDepositAmount       = "TotalCashDepositAmount";
public static final String TallyCash                    = "TallyCash";
public static final String KindPurchase                 = "KindPurchase";

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {

        db.execSQL("create table " +DATABASE_TABLE + "(" 
                + TrnsNo + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," 
                + Enrollment + " text," 
                + Date + " text," 
                + CardNumber + " text,"
                + Time + " text,"
                + ReturnStatus + " text," 
                + EnrollmentAmount + " text," 
                + TotalCashDepositAmount + " text," 
                + TotalCashWithdrawalAmount + " text," 
                + KindPurchase + " text," 
                + TallyCash + " text);");

        Log.e("TransationDb", "Create Succssfully");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion >= newVersion)
            return;

        String sql = null;
        if (oldVersion == 1)
            sql = "alter table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " add note text;";
        if (oldVersion == 2)
            sql = "";

        Log.d("EventsData", "onUpgrade  : " + sql);

        if (sql != null)
            db.execSQL(sql);
    }

}
    public Database open() throws SQLException {

        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public Database(Context c) {
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public void close() {

        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public void insert(TransactionModel TransactionSetter)
    {   
        String iEnrollment                  = TransactionSetter.getEnrollment();
        String iEnrollmentAmount            = TransactionSetter.getEnrollmentAmount();
        String iDate                        = TransactionSetter.getDate();
        String iTime                        = TransactionSetter.getTime();
        String iReturnStatus                = TransactionSetter.getReturnStatus();
        String iCardNumber                  = TransactionSetter.getCardNumber();
        String iTotalCashWithdrawalAmount   = TransactionSetter.getTotalCashWithdrawalAmount();
        String iTotalCashDepositAmount      = TransactionSetter.getTotalCashDepositAmount();
        String iTallyCash                   = TransactionSetter.getTallyCash();
        String iKindPurchase                = TransactionSetter.getKindPurchase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(Enrollment,               iEnrollment);
        contentValues.put(EnrollmentAmount,         iEnrollmentAmount);
        contentValues.put(Date,                     iDate);
        contentValues.put(Time,                     iTime);
        contentValues.put(ReturnStatus,             iReturnStatus);
        contentValues.put(CardNumber,               iCardNumber);
        contentValues.put(TotalCashWithdrawalAmount,iTotalCashWithdrawalAmount);
        contentValues.put(TotalCashDepositAmount,   iTotalCashDepositAmount);
        contentValues.put(TallyCash,                iTallyCash);
        contentValues.put(KindPurchase,             iKindPurchase);

        ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
    }


    public ArrayList<TransactionModel> getReportPrintTrns() {
        ArrayList<TransactionModel> list = new ArrayList<TransactionModel>();

        TransactionModel model = new TransactionModel();

        String whereClause = Enrollment + " in ('CW', 'CD')";

        String[] columns = new String[] { TrnsNo, Enrollment, EnrollmentAmount,
                Date, Time, ReturnStatus, CardNumber,
                TotalCashWithdrawalAmount, TotalCashDepositAmount, TallyCash, KindPurchase };

        Cursor c=ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, whereClause,null,null,null,null);

        int itransno                        =   c.getColumnIndex(TrnsNo);
        int iEnrollment                     =   c.getColumnIndex(Enrollment);
        int iEnrollmentAmount               =   c.getColumnIndex(EnrollmentAmount);
        int iDate                           =   c.getColumnIndex(Date);
        int iTime                           =   c.getColumnIndex(Time);
        int iReturnStatus                   =   c.getColumnIndex(ReturnStatus);
        int iCardNumber                     =   c.getColumnIndex(CardNumber);
        int iTotalCashWithdrawalAmount      =   c.getColumnIndex(TotalCashWithdrawalAmount);
        int iTotalCashDepositAmount         =   c.getColumnIndex(TotalCashDepositAmount);
        int iTallyCash                      =   c.getColumnIndex(TallyCash);
        int iKindPurchase                   =   c.getColumnIndex(KindPurchase);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                model.setTrnsNo(c.getString(itransno));
                model.setEnrollment(c.getString(iEnrollment));
                System.err.println("iEnrollmentType :- "+c.getString(iEnrollment));
                model.setEnrollmentAmount(c.getString(iEnrollmentAmount));
                model.setDate(c.getString(iDate));
                model.setTime(c.getString(iTime));
                model.setReturnStatus(c.getString(iReturnStatus));
                model.setCardNumber(c.getString(iCardNumber));
                model.setTotalCashWithdrawalAmount(c.getString(iTotalCashWithdrawalAmount));
                model.setTotalCashDepositAmount(c.getString(iTotalCashDepositAmount));
                model.setTallyCash(c.getString(iTallyCash));
                model.setKindPurchase(c.getString(iKindPurchase));
                list.add(model);
            } while (c.moveToNext());

        }

        c.close();
        c.deactivate();
        return list;
}

}
```

My SetGet Model

```
package com.example.databasework;

public class TransactionModel {
String TrnsNo, Enrollment, EnrollmentAmount, Date, Time, ReturnStatus,
        CardNumber, TotalCashWithdrawalAmount,
        TotalCashDepositAmount, TallyCash, KindPurchase;

public TransactionModel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    TrnsNo                      = "";
    Enrollment                  = "";
    EnrollmentAmount            = "";
    Date                        = "";
    ReturnStatus                = "";
    Time                        = "";
    CardNumber                  = "";
    TotalCashWithdrawalAmount   = "";
    TotalCashDepositAmount      = "";
    TallyCash                   = "";
    KindPurchase                = "";
}

public String getTrnsNo() {
    return TrnsNo;
}

public void setTrnsNo(String trnsNo) {
    TrnsNo = trnsNo;
}

public String getEnrollment() {
    return Enrollment;
}

public void setEnrollment(String enrollment) {
    Enrollment = enrollment;
}

public String getEnrollmentAmount() {
    return EnrollmentAmount;
}

public void setEnrollmentAmount(String enrollmentAmount) {
    EnrollmentAmount = enrollmentAmount;
}

public String getDate() {
    return Date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    Date = date;
}

public String getTime() {
    return Time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    Time = time;
}

public String getReturnStatus() {
    return ReturnStatus;
}

public void setReturnStatus(String returnStatus) {
    ReturnStatus = returnStatus;
}

public String getCardNumber() {
    return CardNumber;
}

public void setCardNumber(String cardNumber) {
    CardNumber = cardNumber;
}

public String getTotalCashWithdrawalAmount() {
    return TotalCashWithdrawalAmount;
}

public void setTotalCashWithdrawalAmount(String totalCashWithdrawalAmount) {
    TotalCashWithdrawalAmount = totalCashWithdrawalAmount;
}

public String getTotalCashDepositAmount() {
    return TotalCashDepositAmount;
}

public void setTotalCashDepositAmount(String totalCashDepositAmount) {
    TotalCashDepositAmount = totalCashDepositAmount;
}

public String getTallyCash() {
    return TallyCash;
}

public void setTallyCash(String tallyCash) {
    TallyCash = tallyCash;
}

public String getKindPurchase() {
    return KindPurchase;
}

public void setKindPurchase(String kindPurchase) {
    KindPurchase = kindPurchase;
}


}
```

Getting Value

```
 02-14 10:31:23.620: W/System.err(10564): iEnrollmentType :- CW
02-14 10:31:23.620: W/System.err(10564): iEnrollmentType :- CD
02-14 10:31:23.620: W/System.err(10564): iEnrollmentType :- CW
02-14 10:31:23.620: W/System.err(10564): iEnrollmentType :- CW
02-14 10:31:23.620: W/System.err(10564): iEnrollmentType :- CD



02-14 10:31:23.631: W/System.err(10564): CD
02-14 10:31:23.640: W/System.err(10564): CD
02-14 10:31:23.640: W/System.err(10564): CD
02-14 10:31:23.640: W/System.err(10564): CD
02-14 10:31:23.640: W/System.err(10564): CD
```

in Last Fine line i Am getting same value, but database has value like

```
 CW
CD
CW
CW
CD
```

Comment: show your total logcat

Comment: i already show my logcat.... getting value

Comment: When i print in database class iEnrollmentType then i am getting right value but when i getting from array list then its show same value(Last Value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one Problem In getReportPrintTrns() method. you have to initialize your Transaction Model. Like  TransactionModel model=new TransactionModel();

Answer (score 1):

Create each time new object for TransactionModel in **dowhile** as follows

```
public ArrayList<TransactionModel> getReportPrintTrns() {
    ArrayList<TransactionModel> list = new ArrayList<TransactionModel>();

    TransactionModel model;

    String whereClause = Enrollment + " in ('CW', 'CD')";

    String[] columns = new String[] { TrnsNo, Enrollment, EnrollmentAmount,
            Date, Time, ReturnStatus, CardNumber,
            TotalCashWithdrawalAmount, TotalCashDepositAmount, TallyCash, KindPurchase };

    Cursor c=ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, whereClause,null,null,null,null);

    int itransno                        =   c.getColumnIndex(TrnsNo);
    int iEnrollment                     =   c.getColumnIndex(Enrollment);
    int iEnrollmentAmount               =   c.getColumnIndex(EnrollmentAmount);
    int iDate                           =   c.getColumnIndex(Date);
    int iTime                           =   c.getColumnIndex(Time);
    int iReturnStatus                   =   c.getColumnIndex(ReturnStatus);
    int iCardNumber                     =   c.getColumnIndex(CardNumber);
    int iTotalCashWithdrawalAmount      =   c.getColumnIndex(TotalCashWithdrawalAmount);
    int iTotalCashDepositAmount         =   c.getColumnIndex(TotalCashDepositAmount);
    int iTallyCash                      =   c.getColumnIndex(TallyCash);
    int iKindPurchase                   =   c.getColumnIndex(KindPurchase);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            model=new TransactionModel();
            model.setTrnsNo(c.getString(itransno));
            model.setEnrollment(c.getString(iEnrollment));
            System.err.println("iEnrollmentType :- "+c.getString(iEnrollment));
            model.setEnrollmentAmount(c.getString(iEnrollmentAmount));
            model.setDate(c.getString(iDate));
            model.setTime(c.getString(iTime));
            model.setReturnStatus(c.getString(iReturnStatus));
            model.setCardNumber(c.getString(iCardNumber));
            model.setTotalCashWithdrawalAmount(c.getString(iTotalCashWithdrawalAmount));
            model.setTotalCashDepositAmount(c.getString(iTotalCashDepositAmount));
            model.setTallyCash(c.getString(iTallyCash));
            model.setKindPurchase(c.getString(iKindPurchase));
            list.add(model);
        } while (c.moveToNext());

    }

    c.close();
    c.deactivate();
    return list;
}
```

hope it helps you.